# Logout Vk webbrowser

Tags: c#, вконтакте, webbrowser

Сделал авторизацию в webbrowser, но как выйти из учетки вк?
Побывал через https://login.vk.com/?act=logout&hash=14466908cac58bbe4b&_origin=http://m.vk.com открывается страница, в которой написано что браузер не поддерживает js

Comment: Если он не поддерживает куки. то никак не надо. И входить смысла нет.

Comment: Эм... ошибся, не поддерживает js